# onCompleted on Request.GraphUserListCallback doesn't get executed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have this method and the first log prints, the others don't

What am I doing wrong?

That is this :Log.d("insideGetFriends","in"); Gets printed and I looked in my log,

Log.d("facebookError",Integer.toString(graphUsers.size())); and the remaining lines do not get executed.

```
 public ArrayList<ParseUser> getFriends(Session session)
    {
        Log.d("insideGetFriends","in");
        final ArrayList<ParseUser> users=new ArrayList<>();
        Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session,new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> graphUsers, Response response) {

                Log.d("facebookError",Integer.toString(graphUsers.size()));

                for(GraphUser user:graphUsers)
                {
                    String facebookId=user.getId();
                    Log.d("facebookFriend",facebookId);
                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query=ParseUser.getQuery();
                    query.whereEqualTo("facebookID",facebookId);
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
                            users.add(parseUsers.get(0));
                        }

                    });
                }
            }

        });
        return users;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are not starting/executing the request.

You need to store the result of `Request.newMyFriendsRequest(...)` in a variable and then call `.executeAsync()` on it.
This is explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata

Comment: Ya I realized it later. I am sorry I should have deleted the question

Comment: Don't worry about it. In fact, just leave the question up; this way someone else who might do the same thing will be able to find this and realize how to fix their issue quicker.